# Decoding SHA256 password

Tags: c#

I am encoding my password using the code below, how can i decode it to the correct one using `C#`

```
public static string EncodePassword(string password)
{
    var provider = new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider();
    var encoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
    return Convert.ToBase64String(provider.ComputeHash(encoding.GetBytes(password)));
}
```

Comment: You can't. Hash functions are not reversible.

Comment: Actually, to check if your password is fine you should compare a hash of the entered attempt with the hash of your password. Decrypting a password for validation isn't the way to go.

Comment: @Jens,Actually i was testing a functionality in my service and i want to get my current password as i forgot what it was. @ Niyoko, we can't get the hashed string back?, thanks for the info

Comment: @ArjunMenon: You *shouldn't* be able to do that. Passwords should *not* be reversible. If they are, that's a big security vulnerability.

Comment: problem was already asked (and answered) here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10271645/decrypt-from-sha256

Comment: @Jon I had feeling that it should not be reversible but just checking with the techies here :)

Comment: @Misiakw i forgot the password, that's why i asked about decrypting it.Anyway thanks for responding

Comment: The only way to "recover" paswort is to replace SHA hash at database for the new one for password you know. Remember only that if the password is salted in any way, you need to generate new hash also with valid salt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't That is the idea behind password hashing.
You can only check if a password is correct by hashing the input and comparing it
with the stored hash. This is to avoid hackers from stealing your password

Comment: * to make it slower for attackers to get your password. And SHA256 is probably not the password hashing function :)