# Created an encrypted password column, but I can't decrypt it in SQL Server at run time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created an encrypted password column, but when I decrypt it, it displays the null value. When I have to execute a query in SQL Server It decrypts But when I have run my project it can to decrypt a password.

```
insert into [dbo].[Deaf_Login]  
values ('admin', HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', 'admin'), '192.168.43.100', 'a', '12/26/2019')`
```

The above lines is to create the encrypted column in the table.

```
select 
    loginid, username, 
    convert(varchar(60), DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('SHA2_256', vpassword))
from
    Deaf_Login
```

These lines of code, I decrypt that column, but it's not working.

Comment: SHA is hashing, not encryption.

Comment: SHA is not hashing and can you provide more info.

Comment: You can't *dehash* SHA. For 1 SHA word, there exists about an infinity of possible original strings

Comment: `HASHBYTES` definitely is hashing, whatever primitive it's using, and is not a companion function to `DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE`.

Comment: ^-- Yes, `DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE` works with [`ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/encryptbypassphrase-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: If you're trying to understand how to verify an existing password, note that HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', 'admin') will always produce the same result. You should compare hashes, not plaintext passwords.  Also look into: key derivation, salt, pepper. You should never _encrypt_ passwords stored to facilitate user login to your system, only _hash_.

Comment: [This post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords) seems to be quite in-depth.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decrypt from SHA256](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10271645/decrypt-from-sha256)

Comment: @FurkanÖztürk - SHA is hashing.  SHA stands for Secure Hash Algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Hash_Algorithms).

Comment: i am sorry, i try to mean **not encryption**, mistyping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use encryption as `ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('SHA2_256','admin')` 
then you get by `convert(varchar(60),DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('SHA2_256',col_name))`

So first use both side same way.

Answer (score 3):

> It is not possible to decrypt a hash.  This is because hashing does
>   not encrypt the original value at all.  Hashing instead applies a
>   one-way mathematical algorithm to the original value, resulting in a
>   binary value.  Hashed passwords are more secure than password
>   encryption because the hash values can be compared for validation
>   without storing the original password, either encrypted or in plain
>   text:

```
IF HASHBYTES('SHA2_256','admin') = HASHBYTES('SHA2_256',@SuppliedPassword) 
    PRINT 'correct password;
```